# Using synchronization in Java to not allow musical instruments to play together if they're instances of the same sub-class

Tags: java, synchronization

I made three abstract classes to divide instruments : String, Wind, Arc (each one of these extends Thread and specify the run() method. My musical instruments are subclasses of these three. No one sub-class overrides the run() method).
I want that only one instrument for super-class (String, Wind, Arc) plays at the same time. No more than one. How can I do this?

***Re-edit 09/02/2018 08:46 AM*** 
 Thank you @miroh. But I still have the problem. Here I post a class and the Main class when I use it. Can anyone say me how to fix?

**Archi class**

```
package strumenti.archi;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import strumenti.Sound;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;


public class Archi extends Thread{
    String soundFileName;

    public Archi(String soundFileName){
        this.soundFileName = soundFileName;
    }

    private static boolean canPlay = true;
    private static Object playLock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkPlayable();
        try {
            // your code
            play();
        }
        finally { // If a exception happens(or not) during the execution of the code block above, lock must be released.
            synchronized (playLock) {
                canPlay = true; // enable playing for others
                playLock.notifyAll(); // wake up others
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     * This is used to get the lock for the first one to come. Makes other ones wait.
     */
    private static void checkPlayable() { 
        synchronized (playLock) {
            while(!canPlay) {
                try {
                    playLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            canPlay = false;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void play(){  
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFileName);

            // create an audiostream from the inputstream
            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

            // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Cannot play sound.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
   }


}
```

**Main class**

```
package orchestra;

import strumenti.archi.*;

public class Orchestra {

    public static synchronized void main(String[] args) {

        Thread[] strumenti = new Thread[3];
        strumenti[0] = new Archi("sample\\viola.wav");
        strumenti[1] = new Archi("sample\\cello.wav");
        strumenti[2] = new Archi("sample\\violino.wav");
        for(Thread t:strumenti){
            t.start();
        }
        //you should listen the three audio file one after the other
        //but it doesn't work
    }

}
```

Problem solved. Threads have to wait until the audio clip finishes.

Comment: Can you please post your code, that will give some more understanding of your problem.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hYQK_GuI-6-YvyZduVI9uNZ6QKIOy6cD/view?usp=sharing) you can download my code. Class names are in italian. String --> Cordofoni, Wind --> Fiati, Arc --> Archi. Sound is a class whose play() method reproduce wav audio files. I use it to "play" the instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see your code but, If I understand you correctly you can use static lock for this case. Code below is for a single instrument parent. This code makes only one instrument parent is playing in the same time, after one is finished playing the ones that are waiting will be playing one by one.

```
private static boolean canPlay = true;
private static Object playLock = new Object();

@Override
public void run() {
    checkPlayable();

    try {
        // your code
    }
    finally { // If a exception happens(or not) during the execution of the code block above, lock must be released.
        synchronized (playLock) {
            canPlay = true; // enable playing for others
            playLock.notifyAll(); // wake up others
        }
    }

}

/*
 * This is used to get the lock for the first one to come. Makes other ones wait.
 */
private static void checkPlayable() { 
    synchronized (playLock) {
        while(!canPlay) {
            try {
                playLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        canPlay = false;
    }

}
```